# Apache Flume :- Data Pipe line - Kafka-Memory-HDFS

Tags: apache

I have installed Apache Flume 1.6.0 version.
And I wanted to create a data pipeline from Kafka->MemoryChannel->HDFS.

But I got an null pointer exception :- java.lang.NullPointerException which got resolved - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2672

but now i am getting a new exception :- java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource.getBackOffSleepIncrement()J
        at org.apache.flume.source.PollableSourceRunner$PollingRunner.run(PollableSourceRunner.java:136)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)